# Obtener variables después del observable. Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy moviendo el código del componente al servicio y como todo lo hacía el componente , no había ningún problema con el paso de la información a la vista.

Ahora al mover el código al servicio resulta que obtengo diversos errores:

El código original es :

```
export class Usuario {
    user: string;
    name: string;
    mail: string;
    pass: string;
}

LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    public username: string;
    public password: string;
    public errorMessage: string;
    public showAlert: boolean = false;
    public usuario: Usuario = {
        user: '',
        name: '',
        mail: '',
        pass: ''
    }

  public checkCredentials = function() {
    const url = 'assets/users.json';
        this.service.checkCredentials(url).subscribe(users => {
            const checkCookie = this.cookie.get('login');
            if (users.find(u => u.user === this.username)) {
                this.usuario = users.find(u => u.user === this.username);
                if (this.username === this.usuario.user && this.password === this.usuario.pass && !checkCookie) {
                    this.cookie.set('login', this.usuario.mail);
                    this.router.navigate(['configuration']);
                } else {
                    this.errorMesssage = 'Se han introducido unas credenciales incorrectas';
                    this.showAlert = true;
                }
            } else {
                this.errorMessage = 'El usuario introducido no se ha encontrado';
                this.showAlert = true;
            }
        });
```

Como se puede ver aquí lo hace todo el componente.

Y cambiando el código al servicio quedaría:

```
Componente:

  public checkCredentials = function() {
    const url = 'assets/users.json';
    this.service.checkCredentials(url).subscribe();
  }
```

Servicio:

```
export class Usuario {
  user: string;
  name: string;
  mail: string;
  pass: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public username: string;
  public password: string;
  public errorMessage: string;
  public showAlert: boolean = false;
  public usuario: Usuario = {
    user: '',
    name: '',
    mail: '',
    pass: ''
}

  constructor(private cookie: CookieService, private http: HttpClient,private router: Router) { }

  public checkCredentials(url:string):Observable<any>{
     return this.http.get<Object[]>(url).pipe(map(users=> { 
      const checkCookie = this.cookie.get('login');
      if (users.find(u => u.user === this.username)) {
          this.usuario = users.find(u => u.user === this.username);
          if (this.username === this.usuario.user && this.password === this.usuario.pass && !checkCookie) {
              this.cookie.set('login', this.usuario.mail);
              this.router.navigate(['configuration']);
          } else {
              this.errorMesssage = 'Se han introducido unas credenciales incorrectas';
              this.showAlert = true;
          }
      } else {
          this.errorMessage = 'El usuario introducido no se ha encontrado';
          this.showAlert = true;
      }
     }));
  }
```

Los errores son :

```
 u.user -> no existe en el tipo object
 this.usuario -> object no se puede asignar al tipo usuario
 this.errorMesssage -> No existe en el tipo dataService.
```

Finalmente cuando se resuelvan los errores, ¿ cómo mando la información a la vista que en el caso de que sea error,  showAlert  y el mensaje de error se muestre en el html ?

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `this.http.get<Object[]>(url)` por `this.http.get<Usuario[]>(url)`

Comment: gracias, era eso.  =)

Comment: Marca la respuesta como válida para que otros usuarios puedan beneficiarse. Gracias!

Comment: pero en el caso de ser incorrecta, cómo mando las variables al componente ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar:

`this.http.get<Object[]>(url)`

por

`this.http.get<Usuario[]>(url)`

Lo que está ocurriendo es que el tipo especificado es Object en lugar de Usuario, y por eso cuando trata de acceder a esos campos, TypeScript esos errores, ya que en el objeto Object no existe el campo "user" (por ejemplo).

Comment: this.errorMesssage ,
this.showAlert = true; ¿ Cómo mando las variables al componente si falla en el servicio ?

Comment: Lo que el servicio está devolviendo al componente es un Observable, y desde el componente haces la suscripción. Por lo tanto, en caso de error lo que puedes hacer es lanzar un error a través del observable con throw (`Observable.throw(new Error({errorMessage: 'error', showAlert: true }))`). Cuando te subscribas y se produzca el error, el handler asociado al error se ejecutará.

Comment: Enlazo tu misma pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175594/devolver-variables-del-servicio-al-componente-angular2)

Comment: Soy totalmente nuevo, la única forma de manejar errores, fue lo que vi en el tutorial de Héroes y lo sacaba por consola, y eso no me vale..

Comment: Piensa que tienes un return de la petición HTTP, y tal y como indica la signatura de `checkCredentials`, lo que estás devolviendo es un Observable, por tanto, tu respuesta (sea correcta o sea un error) tiene que ser a través de un observable. Queda a tu elección si quieres separar la respuesta correcta de la incorrecta o devolver siempre un objeto que tiene el flag showAlert a true/false según el resultado. En mi opinión, es preferible separarlo pq te dará más claridad en el componente cuando hagas la subscripción.